# Rails model returning nil ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get the id of a certain object. It's probably something really simple that I am missing. The object I need comes out from the database, and I'm able to retrieve its attributes but not the id.

```
Part.where("code ='p8z68vprogen3'").first
# => <Part id: 486, code: "p8z68vprogen3", etc...>


Part.where("code ='p8z68vprogen3'").first.id
# => nil


Part.where("code ='p8z68vprogen3'").first.code
# => "p8z68vprogen3"
```

This is the model:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :build_parts
  has_many :builds, :through => :build_parts
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :code,:link,:description,:category_id
end
```

I suppose it's something related to `attr_accessible` or `attr_accessor`, I tried to fiddle with them but nothing so I ask for help.

EDIT:
asking for a reload returns an error in any way i try i get the object(where or find_by_)

```
part_needed = Part.where("code ='p8z68vprogen3'").first
# => <Part id: 486, code: "p8z68vprogen3", etc..>

part_needed.reload
# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Part without an ID
```

Also, the parts table is already populated, but here is the code that creates an entry:

```
part = Part.new(
    :description => objs[1],
    :code => objs[2],
    :category_id => tips[objs[3].to_i]
)
part.save!
```

This code is executed in another part of the code is not just before where I try to get the ID.

Comment: What do u get when you do **Part.find_by_code('p8z68vprogen3').id** ?

Comment: it returns nil, but **Part.find_by_code('p8z68vprogen3')** is returning the correct object. Also **Part.find_by_id(486)** return the same object.

Comment: What about store `Part.find_by_code('p8z68vprogen3')` in a variable and [`#reload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload) it before asking the `id`?

Comment: What are your rails & ruby versions?

Comment: i updated the question with the results of the reload, ruby version 1.9.3 rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your machine. I know it doesn't sound logical. I encountered a problem where I had two objects of the same class and the first/last method returned the last object. Restarting worked for me. (rails 3.1.1, ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux])
)